# add diffrent intent to each notification

Tags: android

Currently i'm developing android app witch will show notifications(advertisements, discounts avalible and so on) when i'm near some shop. The problem is there could be many shops around and as a result many notifications, so how can i set difrent intents for my notifications if they are generated like this:`

```
private void notifymes(String adress, String prece,int poz) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, showadvert.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("lat", rdat.get(poz).lata);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("longa", rdat.get(poz).longa);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("adr", rdat.get(poz).adrese);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("prece", rdat.get(poz).prece);

            contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            notification = new Notification();
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, prece, adress, contentIntent);
            notification.icon = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync;
            notification.tickerText = "Good deal avalible";
            notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            notificationManager.notify(poz, notification);

    }
```

I would be pleased if you could help me out.

**EDIT:**(data is in sql database)
` As you didn't understand me i will give example. So the example is.....
i have 3 or more notifications witch were generated by some loops and this code. Each of the notification has to pass difrent data to another activity.

Comment: What do you mean under "different intents"? You could add an extra for it.

Comment: I dont quite understand your question? do you have a list of places? ones such as longa, adr, prece etc..? and you want to 'putExtra' them all without typing them one by one? so confused ha

Comment: @xBroak i have in example 3 or more notifications(3 shops with discounts) all of them are in difrent locations and when i click on 1st shop it shows what has a discount and where to find the shop, and when i click on other ones it does the same but it shows what is in those shops. and to your questions answer is yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after 47 minute research i have found out that i have to replace this `contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);`

with this

```
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, myid, notificationIntent, 0);
```

where my id is integer wich is incremented.

Comment: Gotta love simplicity!